# An example of non-invertible operator $F$ such that $P_nF$ is invertible on $\operatorname{Im}P_n$ or proving that It is impossible

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, banach-spaces, operator-theory

Given:

$X$ - any Banach space

$F : X \to X$ (linear bounded and non-invertible)

$P_n$, which is projector that strongly converges to the identity operator $I$ as $n \to\infty$

Can you help me come up with a linear bounded and non-invertible operator $F$ such that the conditions are satisfied:

$P_nFP_n$ is invertible on $\operatorname{Im}P_n$
$\|(P_nFP_n)^{-1} \| < C$ (some constant)
$P_n \to I$ strongly

If you can help at least with idea it also will be great. Thank you very much!
If you think that such example doesn't exist: please can you prove it or help with idea of proving it.

I've tried a lot of things. I'm already desperate, I really hope for your help, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

(In the following I assume that the word "invertible" in the question means "bijective".)

Your assumptions do not imply that $F$ is bijective (however, they imply that $F$ is injective and has closed range, see the partial result below).

**Counterexample.** Let $X = \ell^1$, let $P_n$ be the projection onto the first $n$ components and let $F: \ell^1 \to \ell^1$ be given by
$$
  F(x_1,x_2,x_3,\dots) 
  = 
  (\sum_{k=1}^\infty x_k, x_1, x_2, \dots)
  .
$$
An explicit computation shows that all your assumptions are satisfied. However, the range of $F$ has co-dimension $1$, so $F$ is not surjective.

**Partial results**

(1) Your assumptions imply that $F$ is bounded below (and thus is injective and has closed range).

(2) If, in addition to your assumptions, the dual projections $P_n^*: X^* \to X^*$ also converge strongly to the identity, then $F$ is bijective.

**Proof.**
(1) For each $x \in X$ and each $n$ one has
$$
  \|P_n x\| = \|(P_nFP_n)^{-1}(P_nFP_n)x \| \le C \|P_n F P_n x\|.
$$
By letting $n$ tend to $\infty$ we get $\|x\| \le C \|Fx\|$.

(2) By (1) it suffices to show that $F$ has dense range.
To this end it suffices to show that the dual operator $F^*$ is injective.

Define the operators $G_n := (P_n F P_n)^{-1} P_n: X \to X$. Since $P_n F G_n = P_n$, it follows that $G_n^* F^* P_n^* = P_n^*$, which converges strongly to the identity on $X^*$.

Now if $x^* \in X^*$ satisfies $F^* x^* = 0$, then $F^* P_n^* x^*$ converges strongly to $0$ and since the sequence $(G_n^*)$ is bounded, it follows that $G_n^* F^* P_n^* x^*$ converges strongly to $0$, too.
But from the previous paragraph we know that the same sequence is convergent to $x^*$, so $x^* = 0$. $\square$

Comment: But $F$ is invertible. For example: because $Ker(F) = \{0\}$. Or I am wrong?

Comment: @TorteDeline: If you don't use "invertible" as a synonym for "bijective", could you please specify what definition of the notion you use?

Comment: This [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function). But I understand what you mean: "The inverse of $f$ exists if and only if $f$ is bijective". Yeah, hope so. But it the same moment: if $Ker(F)=\{0\}$ it means that $F$ is invertible. I don't know how to link this two points in this case

Comment: Or maybe Im wrong and this $F$ has another kernel

Comment: Addition: the theorem I’m talking about only works when $F$ is linear, but we are considering such a case, so it still works

Comment: @JochenGluek Probably I understand: In your case $F$ is non-invertible on X. But $F$ is invertible on $Im F$. (if I'm not right please correct me) But in my case It is still consider "invertible".

Comment: @JochenGluek If all that I wrote upper is right: do you have any ideas how to modify your example? Need such $F$ that is non-invertible on Im$F$ and satisfies all another conditions. Thank you very much for your involvement!

Comment: @TorteDeline: If you define invertibility as "bijective onto its range", then what about your assumption that $P_nFP_n$ is "invertible on $\operatorname{Im} P_n$? Do you indeed assume that it is bijective from $\operatorname{Im} P_n$ to $\operatorname{Im} P_n$? Or only that it is bijective from $\operatorname{Im} P_n$ to $\operatorname{Im} P_n FP_n$?

Comment: To get rid of misunderstanding. This defenition of invertible operator I use: 
The invert operator to operator $A$ is an operator that assigns to each $y$ from the set of values ​​$ImA $of operator $A$ a single element $x$ from the domain of a function $D(A)$ of operator $A$, which is a solution to the equation $Ax=y$.

Comment: And of course: operator is invertible when it has invert operator. And it is not invertible when such invert operator doesn't exist

Comment: About your question about: $P_nFP_n$. To be honest: You can choose the easist case. (what is more easy for you to come up example). So, do you have any ideas how to modify your example? And again, thank you very much for involving!!

Comment: @TorteDeline: Well, if the $P_nFP_n$ are bijective from $\operatorname{Im}P_n$ to $\operatorname{Im}P_n$, then there is no counterexample; see the partial result (1) in my answer.

Comment: Apart from this, your definition of invertibility simply means injectivity (which is of course equivalent to having trivial kernel). But calling injectivity "invertibility" in the setting of Banach spaces is really strange terminology because it does not imply that the inverse map is continuous.

Comment: Okay. So lets take $Im P_n$ to $Im P_nFP_n$, as you already mentioned.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about this. We have another terminology probably, I am very sorry about that. In such case as I mentioned, do you have ideas of example? (maybe it is easier than it was before or harder, don't know)

Comment: @TorteDeline: Ok, but checking the proof of (1) shows that the same argument also works if $P_n F P_n$ is only assumed to be bijective from $\operatorname{Im}P_n$ to $\operatorname{Im}P_nFP_n$.

Comment: Hmm. So if my defenition of "invertebility" is injectivity than there are no such counterexample. Because you prove that $F$ is always injective (according to my conditions). Am I right? If so, I will check my defenition, maybe I missed something. But If "our invertebility" equals injectivity so I think it is a key.  I will think about that, thank you

Comment: Yeah, I thoght a little bit and It is true. Looks like "our invertibility" equals injectivity. But if so I have one (hope last) question. Why from: " $F$ is bounded below" follow that $F$ is also injective. Is there theorem or it can be easily showed?

Comment: @TorteDeline: *" Why from: "$F$ is bounded below" follow that $F$ is also injective."* You will certainly figure that out yourself if you simply have a look at the definitions. I feel obliged to point out that, if you are interested in questions like the one that you asked in the original post, it is highly recommendable to acquaint yourself with basic functional analysis.

Comment: Yeah. Few seconds ago I proved it by checking kernel. Thank you very much for your help!